# binding not working windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

hi guys am trying to bind some data. 
i have a list of people . on tap of each of these i take the user to details page.

on tap of each item i get the data from the web and parse it.

```
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> PeopleDetails { get; set; }
```

the above line i have declared in my MainViewModel

ItemViewModel.cs

```
 public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {

      private string _person_name;
    public string _Person_name
    {
        get { return _person_name; }

        set
        {
            if (value != _person_name)
            {
                _person_name= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("_Person_name");
             }
        }
    }

    private string _person_info;
    public string _Person_info
    {
        get { return _person_info; }

        set
        {
            if (value != _person_info)
            {
                _person_info= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("_Person_info");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _person_image_link;
    public string _Person_image_link
    {
        get { return _person_image_link; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _person_image_link)
            {
                _person_image_link= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("_Person_image_link");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

  }
```

on tap of each item am executing the following code

```
       private void getPeopleDetails(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        // Navigate to the new page
        if (e.AddedItems != null && e.AddedItems.Count == 1)
        {
            People selectedItem = (People)e.AddedItems[0];
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PeopleDetailsView.xaml?id="+selectedItem.id, UriKind.Relative));


        }
    }
```

then in PeopleDetailsView.xaml.cs my code is as follows

```
       public PeopleDetailsView()
    {
        DataContext = App.Model;
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded+=new RoutedEventHandler(PeopleDetailsView_Loaded);
    }

    private void PeopleDetailsView_Loaded(Object sender ,RoutedEventArgs e){
        string id = "";
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("id",out id))
        {
            string url = "*****&id=" + id;";

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompletedC);
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
        }
      }

     private void client_DownloadStringCompletedC(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            JToken a = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
            App.Model.PeopleDetails.Add(
             new ItemViewModel()
             {
                 _Person_info = a.SelectToken("info").ToString(),
                 _Person_image_link = a.SelectToken("image_link").ToString(),
                 _Person_name = a.SelectToken("name").ToString(),
             }
            );

        }
        catch (Exception execp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(execp.Message.ToString());
        }

    }
```

and finally am binding the data in my PeopleDetailsView.xaml as follows

```
     <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" DataContext="{Binding PeopleDetails}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="269*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="338*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
        <Image Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,6,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding _Person_image_link}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="246" />
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Height="274" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,42,0,0" Name="scrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="420">
            <TextBlock Height="264" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding _Person_info}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

but  in the PeopleDetailsView i cant see any data being displayed. Please help me

Comment: Could you show us some more info? We'd need to see your ViewModel (ItemViewModel), also, are you sure the remote method actually returns data and that you're parsing it correctly?

Comment: yes am getting the data and parsing it correctly too. ok il add the ItemViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're ViewModel has an ObservableCollection of items and you're binding directly to a property of one of the children. Instead you should use a ListBox and template your binding:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ContentPanel" ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleDetails}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,6,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding _Person_image_link}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="246" />
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Height="274" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,42,0,0" Name="scrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="420">
                <TextBlock Height="264" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding _Person_info}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Yes you do, otherwise it won't update when you add an item to it. If you use the example I just gave it should work